# Spark Streaming Union Stream - parallelization

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, azure-eventhub

This may be a basic question, but I am having some trouble understanding this.

I am currently using the Microsoft Azure Event Hubs Streaming in my Spark/Scala application which is similar to Kafka.

If I created a Unionized stream, I believe this unions multiple DStream objects abstracted to look like a single DStream, will the multiple RDDs in the stream be processed in parallel, or will each RDD be processed individually?

To try and explain this more, here is a quick example:

```
sparkConf.set(SparkArgumentKeys.MaxCores, (partitionCount * 2).toString)

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, streamDuration)

val stream = EventHubsUtils.createUnionStream(ssc, hubParams, storageLevel)
stream.checkpoint(streamDuration)

val strings = stream.map(f => new String(f))
strings.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  rdd.map(f => f.split(' '))
})
```

partitionCount is the number of partitions in the azure event hub.

1. Does the initial "stream.map" perform on each RDD in parallel?
2. Does "string.foreachRDD" process a single RDD at a time, or does it process all the RDDs in some parallel manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After each batch, so after `streamDuration`, Spark will collect all received in this time window data to one RDD, then will map this RDD (again: it's one RDD, but map is done in parallel, just like map in batch job).

As last step, for each RDD your function from `foreachRDD` will be executed. For each RDD means that it will be executed *on RDD from each micro-batch (time window)*.

Of course after next `streamDuration` time, data will be again collected, RDD will be created (data only from time between last collection and current), map, function given to foreachRDD

Summary: foreachRDD doesn't mean that there will be many RDD executed at one time, but it means that in every micro-batch function will be applied to this micro-batch

Comment: vague and thus pretty hard to follow

Comment: @thebluephantom What do you mean? What changes to you suggest?

Comment: Well I have researched the foreachRDD and posted myself as I find the documentation somewhat misleading on it. It is a thorny topic and I see you are ahead of me. But in a court of law  - regardless of the green tick - it is not clear enough to me.